# Is there a better way to get multiple counts?

Tags: mysql

I have data across multiple tables and I would like to generate a page that shows all the relevant counts.  I have googled multiple counts on a query, but can't find anything that works for me as all the date is not in a single table.  I have thought about how to do it using Joins, but can't get it to work.

My MySQL query below works, but takes a good 5-10 seconds to generate the data, which is too long for the small amount of data it is looking at.  So I am looking to learn if there is a better way to do this?

```
SELECT 
T.assetTypeID, 
T.assetType,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM asset A WHERE (T.assetTypeID = A.assetType AND A.location = ".$loc.")) AS asset,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM asset A WHERE (T.assetTypeID = A.assetType AND A.location = ".$loc." AND A.dwgNo <> '' )) AS drawings,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM asset A WHERE (T.assetTypeID = A.assetType AND A.location = ".$loc." AND A.assetStatus = 1)) AS notInstalled,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM asset A WHERE (T.assetTypeID = A.assetType AND A.location = ".$loc." AND A.assetStatus = 3)) AS installed,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM asset A WHERE (T.assetTypeID = A.assetType AND A.location = ".$loc." AND A.assetStatus = 4)) AS PICO,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM asset A WHERE (T.assetTypeID = A.assetType AND A.location = ".$loc." AND A.assetStatus = 5)) AS SAT
FROM 
assettype T
```

The output is a standard table as show below, so I look forward to learning a better way from the mor experienced people on here.
[image]

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, without data I could not test it, but this should work:

```
SELECT 
T.assetTypeID, 
T.assetType,
COUNT(*) AS asset,
COUNT(CASE WHEN A.dwgNo <> '' THEN 1 END) AS drawings,
COUNT(CASE WHEN A.assetStatus = 1 THEN 1 END) AS notInstalled,
COUNT(CASE WHEN A.assetStatus = 3 THEN 1 END) AS installed,
COUNT(CASE WHEN A.assetStatus = 4 THEN 1 END) AS PICO,
COUNT(CASE WHEN A.assetStatus = 5 THEN 1 END) AS SAT
FROM assettype T
INNER JOIN asset A ON T.assetTypeID = A.assetType AND A.location = $loc
GROUP BY T.assetTypeID, T.assetType
```

Comment: this is **vulnerable** to **sql injection**

Comment: Work's perfectly.  Thank you, how is it vulnerable to SQL injection?  because of the variable in it?  The variable is protected.

Comment: Well, the query would be "unsafe", if the variable `$loc` was in any way provided by some user input. OP's question does not mention in any form  how and from where this value is provided, so the assumption of things being "unsafe" is also unsafe.